# Is it possible to manage PAT through the TFS client libraries?

Tags: tfs

We have Azure DevOps Server 2019 (on-prem, do not confuse with Azure DevOps Services 2019, which are hosted in Azure) and unfortunately its REST Api does not support managing PATs. So, I wonder if we could do it using the client libraries.

Does anyone have any example of it? E.g. I want to create/update a PAT to access the Azure Artifacts. How can this be done?

Comment: Hi @mark, what do you mean you can't use the PAT with the REST api in Azure DevOps 2019? You can certainly create them and use them to log in.  What are you trying to do?  If from a custom task for example you can use the SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN environment variable when you enable Oauth in the agent pool that token is always up to date and you don't need to create it.

Comment: I think you are confusing Azure DevOps **Services** 2019 with Azure DevOps **Server** 2019. The latter is an on-prem version and it lacks these abilities. I clarified this point in the post.

Comment: Nope you can use PAT on both on-prem and the service. Check here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops-2019&tabs=preview-page

Comment: Can you refer to me the place in that documentation where they explain how to use it through the API? I am not really interested in the GUI driven approach.

Comment: Like Cece mention bellow, you can't create/revoke PATs via the API since you need a PAT to talk to the API in the first place.  So it needs to be generated via the UI.  But like I mentioned in my first comment.  You can use the SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN in your build/release script by turning on the "Allow scripts to access the OAuth token" in the agent phase.  This token is regenerated for the agent when necessaryand it always valid and secret.

Comment: @Etienne - scripts can authenticate with the on-prem using Active Directory, no PAT is needed. We already have scripts working this way doing other things in TFS and they do not use PAT.

Comment: @mark I have created a feature request in following link: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/925679/api-support-managing-pat.html. You can vote it and product team will evaluate it carefully.

Comment: Upvoted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no client libraries or REST API can manage PAT. You can only create/update PAT within the user interface (UI). You may submit a feature request here:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=22